# How to Change Browser Tab Icon for React Website

Tags: reactjs, json, error-handling, deployment, open-source

[Here Picture to get the idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COmlb.png) I have a website deployed at tustify.com, and I've noticed that the logo displayed on the browser tab is default react logo. I've set up my favicon.ico, and the correct logo shows up when I open the website, but not on the browser tab. How can I change the browser tab icon for my React website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've added your favicon but it can sometimes take a while for browsers to update once they have crawled.

Wait a couple days and it should be good.

Answer (score -1):

Prepare Your Favicon:

Create a favicon image in ICO or PNG format. You can use online tools or create your image. The recommended size is 16x16 pixels.
Place the Favicon in the Public Folder:

Save your favicon image in the public folder of your React project. This folder is usually located at the root of your project.
Update HTML Head in public/index.html:

Open the public/index.html file in your React project.
Locate the  section.
Add the following line inside the  section, replacing 'favicon.ico' with the actual filename of your favicon:

Comment: But the favicon.ico logo is showing on the website when I open the website, logo is only not showing when I search the website at the browser as I attach the pic above on the question. Why is this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).